# Lost typescript support on Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

After to install latest available version of typescript from the web page I lost the support of typescript in my ts files.

To fix my problems I tried:

- Repair VS2015
- Deselect and select again "Tools for Universal Windows App Development" (from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4238)
- Uninstall / Install VS2015
- Reset all setting ... and I am still have the same problem. In the attached image you will see how my ts files looks like, and the error related with reset all settings.[image: error trying reset settings]

---

### UPDATE

The problem with typescript is gone after to clean folder located in:

```
C:\Users\MyUSer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache.
```

If someone give me a good explanation how does work and why my installation failed I will mark your answer as correct.